# Show the equivalence of arc length definitions

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, curves, arc-length

Definition 1:

> Let $r: [a,b] \to \Bbb R^d$ be a continuous differentiable function. Then the arc length is given by $$L(r) = \int_a^b || r'(t) || \, dt$$

Definition 2:

> Let $r: [a,b] \to \Bbb R^d$ be a continuous function. Then the arc length is given by $$ V(r) = \sup_P \sum_{k=1}^n || r(x_k)-r(x_{k-1}) ||$$ where the supremum is taken over all partitions $P = \{a=x_0 \lt x_1 \lt \ldots \lt x_n = b \}$ of $[a,b]$.

How can I show that for a continuous differentiable $r(t)$ the two definitions are equivalent, i.e. $L(r)=V(r)$?

**What I've done so far:**

I found this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137518/determining-the-length-of-a-curve-using-partitions), which shows that I can convert the supremum to a limit

$$V(r) = \sup_P \sum_{k=1}^n || r(x_k)-r(x_{k-1}) || = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n || r(x_k)-r(x_{k-1}) ||$$

by choosing an appropriate sequence of partitions $P_n$ of which I take the $x_k$'s. This gives

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n || r(x_k)-r(x_{k-1}) || = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n || \frac{r(x_k)-r(x_{k-1})}{x_k-x_{k-1}} || (x_k-x_{k-1})$$

Now I somehow need to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n || \frac{r(x_k)-r(x_{k-1})}{x_k-x_{k-1}} || (x_k-x_{k-1}) = \int_a^b ||r'(t)|| \, dt$$

How can I justify this step of converting the sum to an intergral and taking the limit of the inside simultaneously?

Comment: You should show that $\|r(a)-r(b)\|\le V(r)\le L(r)$. Now, define $s(t)$ to be the length of $r$ restricted to $[a,t]$, by the supremum definition. Show that $s'(t)=\|r'(t)\|$, through the definition of the derivative. Finish with the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Alternatively: I think you can use the Mean Value Theorem somehow?

Comment: See related answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3072835/72031 which deals with $d=2$, but the same argument can be used for higher dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Claim.** For a parametrized curve $\gamma \in \mathcal C^1([a,b], \Bbb R^d)$, we have
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \| \gamma(x_{i,n})-\gamma(x_{i-1,n})\| = \int_a^b \|\gamma'(x)\| \,\mathrm dx,
}$$

where $x_{i,n} := a \cdot (1-\frac in) + b\cdot\frac in$.

**Proof.** Note that the left hand side equals
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} 
\underbrace{
\sum_{i=1}^n \left\| \frac{\gamma(x_{i,n})-\gamma(x_{i-1,n})}{\frac{b-a}n}\right\|\cdot {\frac{b-a}n}
}_{=: \kappa_n}
\end{equation}
and observe that $x_{i,n}-x_{i-1,n}=\frac{b-a}n$.

The derivative of $\gamma$ is assumed to be continuous on a compact interval and it is thus also uniformly continuous (cf. Heine-Cantor Theorem), thus there exists a $\delta>0$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$ such that whenever $\lvert t-s\rvert< \delta$, we have
$$
\lVert\gamma'(t)-\gamma'(s)\rVert<\epsilon.
$$
Using the reverse triangle inequality and the fundamental Theorem of calculus, we have
$$\left\lvert\bigg\lVert\frac{\gamma(x_{i,n})-\gamma(x_{i-1,n})}{\frac{b-a}n}\bigg\rVert-\bigg\lVert\gamma'(x_{i,n})\bigg\rVert\right\rvert\le\left\lVert \frac{\gamma(x_{i,n})-\gamma(x_{i-1,n})}{\frac{b-a}n} - \gamma'(x_{i,n})\right\rVert = \frac n{b-a}\left\lVert\int_{x_{i-1,n}}^{x_{i,n}} (\gamma'(t)- \gamma'(x_{i,n}))\,\mathrm dt \right\rVert.$$

By Jensen's inequality,
$$
\frac n{b-a}\left\lVert\int_{x_{i-1,n}}^{x_{i,n}} (\gamma'(t)- \gamma'(x_{i,n}))\right\rVert
\le\frac n{b-a}\int_{x_{i-1,n}}^{x_{i,n}} \lVert \gamma'(t)- \gamma'(x_{i,n})\rVert\,\mathrm dt.
$$
Using uniform continuity, the latter term is now $<\epsilon$ as long as $\frac{b-a}n<\delta$.

In particular, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have
\begin{equation}\tag{*} \label{*}
\left\|\rule{0cm}{1cm}
\underbrace{
  \sum_{i=1}^n 
  \left\|
  \frac{\gamma(x_{i,n})-\gamma(x_{i-1,n})}{\frac{b-a}n}
  \right\|
  \cdot\frac{b-a}n
}_{=\kappa_n}
-\underbrace{
  \sum_{i=1}^n
  \Big\|\gamma'(x_{i,n})\Big\|\cdot\frac{b-a}n 
}_{=:\rho_n}
\right\|
< \varepsilon \cdot (b-a)
\end{equation}
whenever $n>\frac{b-a}\delta$ (note that $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$).

Since the $\rho_n$ are Riemann approximation sums, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \rho_n = \int_a^b \|\gamma'(x)\| \,\mathrm dx$.
By \eqref{*}, we can conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \kappa_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \rho_n$, which proves our claim. $\square$

Comment: @mr_e_man That's a very astute observation, I have edited my answer, please check if it solves the issue you raise.

Comment: Yes, thanks. -- Is it Jensen's inequality? I don't think it has a name. It's just $\lVert\int f\rVert\leq\int\lVert f\rVert$. -- Also, the outer "norm" in $(*)$ is just an absolute value. -- Finally, at the end we need to re-scale $\varepsilon$, and use an $\varepsilon/2$ argument to combine $(*)$ with the two limits (for $\kappa_n$ and $\rho_n$). That's easy enough for me, but perhaps not for other readers.