# Prove equivalence of two definitions of arclength (for non-differentiable curves)

Tags: analysis, curves, arc-length, partitions-for-integration

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^n$ is continuous. For a partition $P=\{t_0=0,t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_{m-1},t_m=1\}$, with norm $|P|=\max_i(t_i-t_{i-1})$, define

$$\sum_P\lVert df\rVert=\sum_{i=1}^m\lVert f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})\rVert,$$
$$S=\sup_P\sum_P\lVert df\rVert,$$
$$L=\lim_{|P|\to0}\sum_P\lVert df\rVert.$$

We want to prove that if either $S$ or $L$ exists, then they both exist and $S=L$.

To be clear, the definition of $L$ is: for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for *all* partitions $P$ with $|P|\leq\delta$, we have $|\sum_P\lVert df\rVert-L|\leq\varepsilon$.

I can see that if $L$ exists then $S$ exists: Take any $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ as above. For any partition $Q$, there is a refinement $P\supseteq Q$ with $|P|\leq\delta$ (e.g. repeatedly bisect the intervals until they're small enough), so $\sum_Q\lVert df\rVert\leq\sum_P\lVert df\rVert\leq L+\varepsilon$, where the first inequality is the triangle inequality. Thus the set of all sums $\sum_Q\lVert df\rVert$ is bounded, and has a supremum $S\leq L+\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we get $S\leq L$. And it's obvious that $L\leq S$.

It remains to be shown that if $S$ exists then $L$ exists. That is, we must show that $S$ satisfies the definition of $L$.

Related: [Determining the Length of a Curve Using Partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137518/determining-the-length-of-a-curve-using-partitions)

Comment: Okay, I found an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3130591/472818

Comment: Just putting the above as a separate duplicate link : [Computing the total variation of a function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ using uniform partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125894/computing-the-total-variation-of-a-function-f0-1-to-mathbbr-using-unifo)